# Does this series (of a form similar to a telescoping series) converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have been trying to solve this problem for awhile, and I can't seem to solve it.Below is the question. I suspect that the series does converge, but I am unable to prove this. Thanks for any help in advance.

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a convergent sequence of real numbers. Can it be concluded that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n+1} - a_{n}|$ converges? Give a proof or a counterexample.

Comment: Hint: It does not necessarily converge.  If the $a_j$'s were monotonic, then this would be telescoping and convergent.  You need something else.  Big hint: if the $a_n$'s were *absolutely convergent* then the sum would converge.

Comment: @Philipp I cannot. I originally though that the series would not necessarily converge, but after trying to do exactly what you have suggested for some time now, I thought that maybe the series does converge.

Comment: Try $a_n = (-1)^n\frac 1 n$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I tried that earlier, and I guess I made a mistake, because now I have worked out on paper. This is indeed a proper counterexample. Thank you. If you put the solution below, I will mark it so that you receive some credit.

Comment: Note that even if you can't find a counterexample (the one just given by @FriedrichPhilipp, for instance), the statement you ask *has to be false* ("morally"). Otherwise, it would imply that every convergent series is absolutely convergent... (Take you favorite convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$. Define $A_n = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n$, so that $(A_n)_n$ is a convergent sequence of real numbers. What is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (A_{n+1}-A_n)$? What would be $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lvert A_{n+1}-A_n\rvert$?)

Comment: @ClementC. Please write an answer. I like your more general argument more than my particular example.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Sure -- done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a comment above:
Note that even if you can't find a counterexample (the one given in the comments above by @FriedrichPhilipp, for instance), the statement you ask **has** to be false ("morally"). Otherwise, it would imply that every real-valued convergent series is absolutely convergent: and *you know that to be false.*

To see why, take you favorite convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$. Consider the partial sum $A_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$, so that $(A_n)_n$ is a convergent sequence of real numbers. Now, what is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(A_{n+1}−A_n)$? What would be $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lvert A_{n+1}−A_n\rvert$?

---

Note that instantiating the above with a series you know to be conditionally convergent (convergent, but not absolutely convergent) will give you a counter-example.